# Where does the line x = 2 − t, y = 3t, z = −1 + 2t intersect the plane 2y + 3z = 6?

Tags: geometry, parametric

form this `2y + 3z = 6` equation i take the `x = 0`. therefor `2 - t = 0` and `t = 2`. then i got `y = 6` and `z = 3` respectively from `y = 3t, z = −1 + 2t`. 
but the value does not satisfy the equation `2y + 3z = 6`.
was my approach wrong ? if then how to solve it ?
sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Since the equation of the plane doesn't involve $x$, the value of $x$ can be *anything*. It doesn't have to be zero. (This is a classical beginner's mistake.)

Comment: Perhaps it will help to write your equation as $0\cdot x + 2y + 3z = 6$. Can you see that $x$ need not be $0$, indeed, could be any real value?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to you, $\;y=3t\;,\;\;z=-1+2t\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R$ , so that

$$6=2y+3z=2\cdot3t+3(-1+2t)=-3+12t\iff t=\frac34$$

Take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Express $\,2y + 3z = 6\,$ in terms of $t$, and solve.

$$2(3t) + 3(-1 + 2t) = 6 \iff 6t + 6t-3 = 6 \iff 12t = 9\iff t =\dfrac 34$$

Now find $x, y, z$ at $t = \dfrac 34.$